# In JavaScript: How do I add a parameter to an existing function?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

Javascript novice here. There's been a lot written on this subject, but I can't find the answer (so what I'm trying to do is probably bad form):

I can add a property to an existing function, but **I'd like to know if I can add a new parameter to a function (without just overwriting the function).**

Take an existing function (I happen to be using this one as a constructor function):

```
function Employee(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

I'd like to add a "job" property. I could write

```
Employee.job = job;
```

But Employee only has one parameter ("name"). I want to give the Employee function an additional parameter: "job".

So the desired end result would look like:

```
function Employee(name, job) {
    this.name = name;
    this.job = job;
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `Employee.job = job;` adds a static property to the function. It won't be accessible by instances of `Employee` which are created using `new Employee()`. Why don't you want to change the function? Only thing you can do is prototype inheritance and create a new function

Comment: Are you saying uodate parameter at run time ?

Comment: In this case, yes (I'm experimenting in the Chrome debug console), but I'd be interested in finding a solution that works in any scenario.

Comment: @adiga I want to add a parameter to the constructor function so `job` _isn't_ static. The goal is: when I do `let employee1 = new Employee (name, job)` I can pass whatever name and job I want into the new object.

Comment: The best way is to just rewrite the `Employee` function to the desired code. Why would you want to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can **override** the function by adding a wrapper on top of it. Hope this helps.

```
function Employee(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

function createWrapper(functionToWrap){

 return function EmployeeWrapper(name,job){
   let employeeInstance = new functionToWrap(name);
   employeeInstance.job = job;
   return employeeInstance;
  }

}

Employee = createWrapper(Employee);
employeeInstance = new Employee('name','job');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it just as you have described in the question.

Just one change. Adding a variable to the constructor directly like this `Employee.job = job;` will make it static. Instead add this variable to its object. Check out the following snippet...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>

    <h2>JavaScript Object Constructors</h2>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        // Constructor function for Person objects
        function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
            this.firstName = first;
            this.lastName = last;
            this.age = age;
            this.eyeColor = eye;
        }

        // Create 2 Person objects 
        var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
        var myMother = new Person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");

        // Add nationality to first object
        myFather.nationality = "English";

        // Display nationality 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "My father is " + myFather.nationality; 
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @flightPlan did it solve your problem? If yes, then do accept the answer. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Hi @Deepak Thank you for your answer, but I don't think this quite solves it. Using your example: I'd like to add a parameter to the "constructor function for Person objects" itself (after it's already been initialized). So whenever I'm using `new Person` The new person accepts the argument "nationality".  The first line of the constructor function would be `function Person(first, last, age, eye, nationality)`.

Comment: so, you want to alter the constructor definition and want to use the updated construction thereafter, right?

Comment: Correct. Ideally without overwriting the function.